# How to reduce multiple insert into in postgresql?

Tags: postgresql

is it possible to reduce a multiple insert into in PostgreSQL.

i have this:

```
insert into table (id,name,city)
values ('1','Mike','Orleans')

insert into table (id,name,city)
values ('2','Paul','Paris')
```

so i have to insert more than 100 datas.
Can we do it in one query

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

```
insert into the_table (id,name,city)
values 
  (1,'Mike','Orleans'),
  (2,'Paul','Paris');
```

If `id` is an integer column, then don't provide a string value for it. `'1'` is a string (character) value. Numbers are specified **without** single quotes: `1` is a number.